# Java-XML parsing for data

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file with the following data:

```
<TextType name="ExtraBig_22p">
<font name="Optima" size="18" style="BOLD" env="osx" lang=""/>
<font name="Cyberbit" size="22" style="PLAIN" env="any" lang="Chinese"/>
<font name="Cyberbit" size="22" style="PLAIN" env="any" lang="Korean"/>
<font name="Calibri_bold" size="22" style="BOLD" env="default" lang=""/>
</TextType>
<TextType name="Big_18p">
<font name="Optima" size="16" style="BOLD" env="osx" lang=""/>
<font name="Cyberbit" size="18" style="PLAIN" env="any" lang="Chinese"/>
<font name="Cyberbit" size="18" style="PLAIN" env="any" lang="Korean"/>
<font name="Calibri_bold" size="18" style="BOLD" env="default" lang=""/>
</TextType>
```

When i parse this i get lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You `xml` is not a `valid` xml. To validate it add a root element to the top of the document.

```
<root>

xml content

</root>
```

Check here  [xml validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

For `xml` to be valid :

1. The XML document must have one root element.
2. XML elements must be closed in the order they are opened.
3. Any entities that are referenced in the document must also be well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Your document doesn't have a root element: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element